# Quiero saber si las etiquetas o grupos en la Api de Google People fueron eliminadas

Tags: google-apps-script

Tengo una consulta breve. **Estoy buscando como etiquetar a varios contactos** con la Api de Google People y no consigo información al respecto.

**¿Acaso ya no es posible hacerlo?**

Busque información al respecto y eso es lo que entiendo por acá:  https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/contactGroups.members/modify?hl=es-419

Comment: Hola. Según indica la documentación, ese es el método que debes usar y dice además: *Los únicos grupos de contactos del sistema a los que se pueden agregar miembros son `contactGroups/myContacts` y `contactGroups/starred`. Otros grupos de contactos del sistema dejaron de estar disponibles y solo se pueden quitar los contactos.* ¿Cuál es el problema exactamente? ¿Qué es lo que quieres hacer? ¿A qué te refieres con "etiquetar"? Revisa la nueva API, quizá debas cambiar algunas prácticas, casi siempre para mejorar el entorno, aunque ello suponga actualizar o normalizar algunas cosas.

Comment: Quiero que los contactos que lleguen a un sheets desde un Google Forms, se registren automáticamente en Google Contactos y en un grupo o etiqueta en específico, así como lo permitía la API de Contacto, antes que la hicieran obsoleta.

Comment: Te aconsejo no insistir en hacer cosas obsoletas, se declaran tales porque son inseguras o porque hay mejores formas de hacer las cosas. No sé cuál sea el caso aquí. Lo cierto es que casi siempre puedes lograr lo mismo de una forma más sencilla. Cuando una API evoluciona siempre es a mejor no a peor.